# how to get value of added text box

Tags: javascript, java, html

Need help in the following snippet to get the value
Unable to work as find of the value is different

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var element = document.getElementById('grdgjj');
            if (value == 'hfhkk')
                element.style.display = 'block';
          
        }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="hfhj">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Bsnsjs">trst</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select required
                    class="form-control"
                    name="hdhsksks"
```

Comment: What do you mean by `value of "specificRegion"`? In your case `specificRegion` is your option value. Do you mean the `text` of the option?

Comment: yes, text of the option

Comment: I think I misunderstood your problem. I thought it's the `text of option` like you said, but it turns out to be text of  `input[type=text]`?

Comment: I interpret this as follows: You want to use the `value` of the region selection as the input to the program _**unless**_ "Specific Region" is selected — in _that_ case you want to use the value taken from the `which_region` input field. If this is what you want then your code will have to check for "specificRegion" and fetch the value from the input field. (but the question is _not clear_ on what you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect to get the value of `input[type=text]` when `specificRegion` option is selected, then what you should do is:

1. When`OnChange` event fired, check if `specificRegion` **option** is selected or not.
2. If **yes**, get the value of `input[type=text]`.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function specific_region(select) {
            var element = document.getElementById('others');
            var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
            if (value == 'Specific Region'){
                element.style.display = 'block';
                var text = document.getElementById('others').value;
                alert("Region: '" + text + "'");
            }
            else{
                element.style.display = 'none';
                alert(select.value);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="buildStart">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="which_region">Region</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select required
                    class="form-control"
                    name="region"
                    cam-variable-name="which_region"
                    cam-variable-type="String"
                    onchange="specific_region(this);">
                <option value="management">Management</option>
                <option value="specificRegion">Specific Region</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <input class="form-control"
                   id="others"
                   name="which_region"
                   style='display:none;'/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: if I am using "which_region" this value to get the string, it is still returning me `specificRegion`
is there a way it can return the text/value of the input box

Comment: Yes, **this.value** will return `value="specificRegion"` attribute inside `<option>` tag. So you need to pass **this** instead of **this.value**. If you pass **this**, you still can retrieve **this.value** inside your function, simply with `select.value`. You can try to add this `alert(select.value)` inside your `which_region` function.

Comment: I think we are talking different context, you are saying that if you will get the value of `which_region` with the above program - it will return the string that has been typed and not actually `specificRegion`

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure if this is what you mean. You'll never be able to get the input[type=text] value by using Select element `this.value`. What you can do: First, you check if `Specific Region` is selected or not, if selected, then you get the value of `input[type=text]` with `id='others'`

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the text of an option field through its `text` property.

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
console.log(select.options[0].text)
console.log(select.options[1].text)
```

```html
<form name="buildStart">
  <select>
    <option value="management">Management</option>
    <option value="specificRegion">Specific Region</option>
  </select>
</form>
```